# What is the idiomatic way to access part of Algebraic data type in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

There is an easier way to call function `test` with value `x` than using `case` expression?

```
data FooBar = Foo Int | Bar String

test :: Maybe Int -> Bool -- Int from Foo constructor

x :: FooBar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easier way is to define a helper to get you part of the way there:

```
data FooBar = Foo Int | Bar String

foo :: FooBar -> Maybe Int
foo (Foo x) = Just x
foo _ = Nothing

test :: Maybe Int -> Bool
x :: FooBar

result :: Bool
result = test . foo $ x
```

If you're the one defining `test`, you could also just define it differently to make things easier on yourself:

```
test' :: FooBar -> Bool
test' (Foo x) = (some logic)
test' _ = (the default value)
```

There is a neat concept called a "prism" that models this general concept -- extracting pieces of data from sum types -- elegantly. But they're... kind of hard to understand, and whether or not they can be considered "idiomatic" is pretty controversial.

Comment: Based on the wording of the question and the type signature of `test`, I didn't think bringing up prisms was a good idea;)

Answer (score -1):

You could use guards or pattern matching in the functions you are handing a `FooBar` as an argument.